# Indexing a view with multiple references to the same table

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

All of our objects are versioned, which means all our tables have `Id` and `Version` columns, so there are multiple rows per `Id`, one for each version. Another table called `ObjectManager` contains the `CurrentVersion`. So by joining a table to that, we can get the table row having the latest version.

I'm trying to full text search a view of three of these tables joined together. Each one has to have its own join to `ObjectManager` but that prevents indexing and gives the error about self joins.

What is the general approach to work around this? Once the solution is set up, I don't want to have to do anything to maintain it, preferably.

```
create view v_AACOPolicySearch 
with schemabinding as
select p.Id, p.ReferenceNo, a.name Agent, c.Name Client
from dbo.AACOPolicy p join
dbo.Agent a on p.Agent = a.id join
dbo.CLClient c on p.Client = c.Id join
dbo.ObjectManager op on p.Id = op.Id and p.VersionNo = op.CurrentVersionNo join
dbo.ObjectManager oa on a.id = oa.Id and a.versionNo = oa.CurrentVersionNo join
dbo.ObjectManager oc on c.Id = oc.Id and c.VersionNo = oc.CurrentVersionNo
where p.ReferenceNo like 'YDS%'

create unique clustered index UQ_AACOPolicySearch on dbo.v_AACOPolicySearch (Id)
```

> Msg 1947, Level 16, State 1, Line 84 Cannot create index on view
>   "AACO_TEST.dbo.v_AACOPolicySearch". The view contains a self join on
>   "AACO_TEST.dbo.ObjectManager".

Bear in mind this statement will be followed by:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON v_AACOPolicySearch(ReferenceNo, Agent, Client)
KEY INDEX UQ_AACOPolicySearch ON AACO_TEST_FULLTEXT
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

The reason why I don't think this is a duplicate is because no one has ever answered a real work around. They have explained why it's not possible, but that's it.

I'm not in control of all of the code that hits `Agent` or `CLClient`. So, if I add a `uniqueidentifier` column to them, I have little or no idea what that will break. It may be possible but it would be very scary.

Comment: What you want isn't possible. The only work-around I can think of off the top of my head is a process that runs periodically (set up a SQL Job) that copies the data from a normal view into a persistent table, which you can then index as you desire. This may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: @pmbAustin, what I asked for was a general approach to a work-around. lol you said it's not possible then you proved it is possible. Why don't you make an answer and let's see if there are any easier ways to that; probably not. ;)

Comment: I don't consider it an answer, really. It's a hack, and requirements would dictate whether it's an acceptable one or not. Feel free to try that sort of implementation (which is basically a 'snapshot the data, index it, and after some period of staleness is reached, throw it away, snapshot again, index again, rinse-repeat". If it works for you, great. It's not a general answer to the problem though, imho.

Comment: @pmbAustin, ok, we are doing the hack now. So, if you `delete * from MyStagingTable` and then `insert MyStagingTable select * from v_AACOPolicySearch`, you have to `drop` and re-`create` the full text index?

Comment: I'd TRUNCATE rather than delete * (especially if you have a ton of data), and yeah, you'll have to drop and re-create the full-text index catalog.